# Is $\mathbb{R}$ the only unbounded, closed and open non-empty set?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a non-empty set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $A$ be unbounded, closed and open. Then is it true to say $A = \mathbb{R}$? Is $\mathbb{R}$ the only choice in this case? I am inclined to say yes.

Comment: Do you know about connectedness?

Comment: @Randall I know an informal definition that says if you start from a point in your domain and can get to any other point in your domain without going out of domain, then the domain is connected. I hope this is what you are referring to.

Comment: Eh, kinda sorta.  It turns out that your hunch is right, even without assuming unboundedness.

Comment: Surely you mean to have additional stipulations on $A$ such as $A$ being a subset of $\Bbb R$ in the first place... else you could just have a set that is defined almost identically to $\Bbb R$ and is isomorphic, homeomorphic, and whatever else similar to $\Bbb R$ but where it is defined in such a way as to not be identically *equal* to $\Bbb R$.  Even without that sort of pedantic answer, you have things like $\Bbb R^n$ which are also unbounded clopen sets within their own topologies...

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, A is a subset of R. I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Under the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ it is true that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$ are the only sets which are both closed and open, so if your set $A$ must be nonempty then you are correct.